# How to remove one instance of an object using Java ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

If I have two ArrayList `list`  and `toremove` , and I want to delete all the objects on `list` that are equals to objects on `toremove`. But only once (one instance of the object). How can I achieve that in Java ? Do I have to manually loop through all `toremove` objects and delete it if it in `list`?

I have tried `.removeAll(toremove);` but it deletes every instance if objects.

for example, if i have `book1 book1 book2 book3`, and my `toRemove` list is `book1 book2`. the output will be `book1 book3`.

```java
    private List<Book>  removeList(List<Book> initial,List<Book> toremove) {
        List<Book> list=initial;

        for (Book book : List) {

        }

        return List;
    }
```

Comment: Btw, please don't capitalize your variables. `List List=Initial` makes for some very confusing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `equals()` in book class

```
static class Book {
        int id;
        String title;

        public Book(int id, String title) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Book other = (Book) obj;
            return this.title.equals(other.title);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + ": " + title;
        }
    }
```

And remove the first occurrence of the object in the list using `remove()`

```
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Book b1 = new Book(1, "book1");
        Book b2 = new Book(1, "book1");
        Book b3 = new Book(3, "book2");
        Book b4 = new Book(4, "book3");
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(b1);
        list.add(b2);
        list.add(b3);
        list.add(b4);
        removeFirstOccurance(list, Arrays.asList(b1, b3));
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static void removeFirstOccurance(List<Book> list, List<Book> toRemove) {
        for (Book b : toRemove) {
            list.remove(b);
        }
    }
```

, output

```
[1: book1, 4: book3]
```

Comment: but this removes all instances of a book right?, i want it to delete only one

Comment: No, it removes the book of id 1

Comment: but if i have multiple books with id 1?

Comment: So you want to remove only one book of id 1?

Comment: It will remove all objects from `toRemove` list if exists in 'list'

Comment: for example, if i have book1 book1 book2 book3, and my toRemove list is book1 book2. the output will be book1 book3.

Comment: So .remove() only remove one instance? its seems to work

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
for (Book b : toremove) {
  int index = list.indexOf(b);
  if (index != -1) list.remove(index);
}
```

This finds the index of your object, and then removes it using that index as long as that book is present in `list`.

Of course, as sc0der said, you'll have to override the equals method for the `Book` class, but I suspect you've already done that, since `removeAll` does work in that it removes all objects.

Example input:

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(book1);
list.add(book1);
list.add(book2);
list.add(book1);
list.add(book3);
toremove = Arrays.asList(new Book[]{book1, book2});
```

Example output:

```
list = [book1, book1, book3]
```

Comment: ohhh i'm gonna try that

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
private static List<Book> removeList(List<Book> initial, List<Book> toRemove) {
    List<Book> toBeReturned = new ArrayList<Book>(initial);
    List<Book> deleted = new ArrayList<Book>();
    Iterator<Book> itr = toBeReturned.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Book a = itr.next();
        for (Book b : toRemove) {
            if (b.equals(a) && !deleted.contains(b)) {
                deleted.add(b);
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    return toBeReturned;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

class Book {
    int id;

    public Book(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Book other = (Book) obj;
        return this.id == other.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Book> initial = new ArrayList<Book>();
        initial.add(new Book(1));
        initial.add(new Book(1));
        initial.add(new Book(1));
        initial.add(new Book(2));
        initial.add(new Book(2));
        initial.add(new Book(3));

        List<Book> toRemove = new ArrayList<Book>();

        toRemove.add(new Book(1));
        toRemove.add(new Book(2));

        List<Book> list = removeList(initial, toRemove);

        // Display list
        list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<Book> removeList(List<Book> initial, List<Book> toRemove) {
        List<Book> toBeReturned = new ArrayList<Book>(initial);
        List<Book> deleted = new ArrayList<Book>();
        Iterator<Book> itr = toBeReturned.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Book a = itr.next();
            for (Book b : toRemove) {
                if (b.equals(a) && !deleted.contains(b)) {
                    deleted.add(b);
                    itr.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        return toBeReturned;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Book [id=1]
Book [id=1]
Book [id=2]
Book [id=3]
```